# ipconfig not working

Tags: command-line

For some reason when I enter `ipconfig` in terminal, it just returns this:

```
No command 'ipconfig' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tpconfig' from package 'tpconfig' (universe)
 Command 'iwconfig' from package 'wireless-tools' (main)
 Command 'ifconfig' from package 'net-tools' (main)
ipconfig: command not found
```

Not quite sure what the issue is here or how to approach this

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Ubuntu/Linux equivalent of *ipconfig* in Windows is **ifconfig**.

Try typing `sudo ifconfig`.

The result will look something like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:94:37:b6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.231  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe94:37b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:519374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110611 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:332864737 (332.8 MB)  TX bytes:11113451 (11.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:33651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:33651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2951078 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:2951078 (2.9 MB)
```

Comment: I... I am an idiot.

Comment: This answer was written in 2012, but already back then (and even more now), "ifconfig" was being deprecated. It should be pointed out that the "ip" command will replace it, and the more "modern" way of checking your IP would be `ip addr show`. More info: https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig

Comment: You don't need sudo to run ifconfig

Answer (score 9):

ipconfig is a Windows program - the closest for linux is ifconfig, but contrary to what others (including the accepted "answer") are saying, it is **not** the same, and does not give the same output at all.

One of the key missing pieces of information in ifconfig is the DNS addresses; they are not there, and there's not an easy way to find that out.  On my system, I have an alias to show some information like that:

`nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4`

This will list most of the information I usually want to see.  On my system, it shows:

```
$ nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4
IP4-SETTINGS.ADDRESS:                   192.168.1.110
IP4-SETTINGS.PREFIX:                    24 (255.255.255.0)
IP4-SETTINGS.GATEWAY:                   192.168.1.1
IP4-DNS1.DNS:                           8.8.8.8
IP4-DNS2.DNS:                           8.8.4.4
```

Note that you may need to use a different designation for the network, such as `eth1`, `eth2`, etc.  If you get an error about a device not found, try changing this.

Also note the accepted "answer" is also incorrect in that you do not need to use "sudo" for this command.

Comment: thank for a hint. `nmcli dev show wlp1s0 | grep IP4` has shown me data

Answer (score 8):

If that's the case, use ifconfig. It'll give you the same output that ipconfig will on Windows. But `ifconfig` is now `ip a`.

```
ifconfig
```

is equivalent to

```
ip addr show
```

and, because the object argument can be abbreviated and command defaults to show, also to

```
ip a
```

Comment: Would recommend just using the **ip** version.  Using ifconfig would require installing net-tools.

Comment: This link be helpful "https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-find-my-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux"

Comment: this response is very helpful... thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're looking for the command that will display the same info `ipconfig` does on Windows.

If that's the case, use `ifconfig`, part of the `net-tools` package. It'll give you the same output that `ipconfig` will on Windows.

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Answer (score 3):

2020 UPDATE (Ubuntu 18+)

Still, use `nmcli` as an equivalent command as Marty Fried suggests.

Coming from Windows, when you do `ipconfig` you probably expect to see a bunch of information such as the network interfaces, ipv4, ipv6 addresses, dns server, default gateways etc. Unfortunately, and as Marty Fried mentions in his answer, `ifconfig` is hard to extract this information (I'm not even sure it has it at all) so I would say `ifconfig` and `ip addr show` are not really equivalent commands to `ipconfig` because they are missing all this information.

However you can use `nmcli`:

```bsh
nmcli dev show eth0
```

Explanation:

You can first list all your network interface devices to get the device name:

```bsh
nmcli dev show | grep DEVICE

# output
: '
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp5s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         br-877527cf5a41
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         veth9938f55
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         veth9d03338
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
'
```

or to also see the network device type:

```bsh
nmcli dev show | grep -E 'DEVICE|TYPE'

# output
: '
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         br-877527cf5a41
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         veth9938f55
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         veth9d03338
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
'
```

In my case I'm only interested in my wifi so i'm going to use the `GENERAL.DEVICE` name of my `GENERAL.TYPE: wifi`  and:

```bsh
nmcli dev show wlp5s0

# output
: '
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         34:DE:1A:6D:9B:51
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     room-501
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.8.101/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.8.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.8.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.8.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.8.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::710e:1bee:cdb4:e281/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
'
```

Here's a function you can add to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`:

```bsh
function ipconfig() {
    for i in `seq 1 100`; do printf "-"; done; echo "";
    nmcli dev show $1 | grep -E 'DEVICE|TYPE|HWADDR|MTU|STATE|CON|ADDRESS|GATEWAY|ROUTE|DNS|DOMAIN|^$' | awk '!NF{for(i=0; i<=100; i++) printf "-";}1';
    for i in `seq 1 100`; do printf "-"; done; echo "";
}
```

Usage:

```bsh
ipconfig # show details of all devices
ipconfig eth0 # show only details of eth0
```