# Can't Access Apache on VirtualBox VM (using NAT + Host-only)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache2

### Short Description:

My host OS is Ubuntu-12.04 and using VirtualBox I have set up a VM of Oracle Linux 6.4 (based on RHEL) with Apache httpd web server. I need to access the web pages served by the VM from my host Ubuntu.

---

### Additional Details:

Here are the configurations:

- The 1st network adapter of the VM is configured as `NAT`, since I need it to use the host's Internet connection. See image below:

  NAT configuration of 1st adapter:
  [image: NAT configuration of 1st adapter]
- I have enabled a 2nd adapter as Host-only, so I can access the VM from the host (`ssh` or `scp` to guest VM from host, etc). This is working fine. The IP of the guest VM is manually set to `10.10.10.15` and I can successfully `ping`, `ssh` and `scp` to the guest VM without any problem. See below:

  Host-only configuration of 2nd adapter:
  [image: Host-only configuration of 2nd adapter]

Inside the VM, I have set up Apache successfully and it's working for `localhost` but when I try to access the page from the host, by entering `10.10.10.15` in Chromium or Firefox, it fails to connect!  **`:(`**

I have also tried to add an entry inside `/etc/hosts` as follows, but entering `test-website.net` inside Chromium or Firefox still gives the same error!  **`:(`**

```
10.10.10.15    test-website.net
```

One more thing to note is about `SELinux`. As you might know, `SELinux` is enabled by default on RHEL-based distros such as CentOS and Oracle-Linux. To make sure that SELinux is not messing up my work, I have configured it to `permissive` mode in `/etc/selinux/config` and confirming the effect after reboot using `sestatus`:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy version:                 26
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

---

This may sound like a duplicate of the following questions, but the answers in these questions suggest to set up a `Host-only` adapter for the guest and configure `/etc/hosts` in the host, which **I have already tested and didn't work for me**:

- [Question #1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/)
- [Question #2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222563/)

Any help?!

Comment: If you run `wget 10.10.10.15` in the host, what error does it display?

Comment: @ignis Here is the output for `wget 10.10.10.15` : `Connecting to 10.10.10.15:80... failed: No route to host.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the problem ... **`iptables`**!

The configuration I have set up for the VM should work without any problem.

If anyone with the same setup is facing problems, checkout the following:

- System firewall (i.e. `iptables`) configuration;
- `SELinux` configuration;

cheers **`:)`**

Comment: To manually turn off iptables in the guest: sudo service iptables stop

Comment: Turning off iptables should not be the solution!

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta Yes, turning off `iptables` can have security consequences and it is only recommended for  controlled test environments. For a production system the correct way is to configure `iptables` to allow the desired traffic to pass in and out.

Comment: Thanks its always `iptables` and yes, selinux is a "problem, too". If you want to connect to the host using mod_proxy, make sure to call `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`, too. See for example https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/13permission-denied-proxy-http-attempt-to-connect-to-127-0-0-18080-localhost-failed/

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind apache to all interfaces or just `lo`?

BTW: You don't have to use a 2nd network (host only) so as to access the guest services.

By using [NAT port forwarding](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward), you can set up rules to map web and ssh/sftp/ftp ports so that you can access those by accessing localhost:PORT on the host.

For example to map guest ssh to host port 2222, you can access it by `ssh -p 2222 user@localhost`

`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"`

**NOTE**: Forwarding host ports < 1024 impossible, it is a NAT limitation.

Comment: Actually I didn't do anything special after installing Apache with YUM, other than starting the `httpd` service. What should I do ?

Comment: `yum`... that is CentOS/RHEL, this is for Ubuntu/Debian, wrong place...

Comment: I did mention in the question that the VM is Oracle Linux which is based on RHEL ... Can you please explain your note on binding Apache to all interfaces ... What exactly should I do to fix my problem?

Comment: In your site's configuration file, what did you bind to? e.g. `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: I haven't done any binding. Actually I don't need the server to be accessed by a name. The VM's IP address (i.e. `10.10.10.15`) is fine if it works ...

Comment: Do a `netstat -nap | grep :80` see if it's binding to 10.10.10.15, also ping the IP and make sure you can reach it (there is route).