# VirtualBox apache

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

I have created a simple Ubuntu Server on VirtualBox. I wanted to run Apache server but I can't acces the website from any other device.

I have checked that Apache is listening on port 80 using `apache2.conf`.

```
netstat -tnl | grep :80<br>
tcp6 0 0 ::80 :::* LISTEN

service apache2 status<br>
*apache2 is runnig
```

I can ping the ip of vbox on host, but can't ping host on vbox.

I have bridge adapter network on vbox setting.

And I can access the website on vbox machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get apache to serve a site via VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222563/how-to-get-apache-to-serve-a-site-via-virtualbox)

Comment: I doubt it - OP said he **is** using bridged mode.

Comment: What does it mean "can ping the ip of vbox on host, but can't ping host on vbox". Are you trying to ping using its name?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the netstat commands shows that apache is listening on the IPv6 port 80 only.

For starters try to force apache to use IPv4 (for an example see https://www.rackaid.com/blog/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-apache-server/ ) and try again.

Comment: I would NOT recommend disabling IPv6. Instead, just find a way to enable both if they aren't already.

Comment: I have add `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` but it doesn't work. And turn of the firewall by `iptables -F` `ufw disable`